# How to redirect to other html page using angularjs ng-route

Tags: angularjs

Whwn I click on signUp button in signUp.html page,it should redirect to signIn.html page.But I'm unable to redirect to signIn.html page.Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

My signIn.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="wrapper" align="center">
        <div>
            <img id="imgDiv" src="images/favicon.png">
        </div>
        <div id="loginDiv">
            <h3>LogIn</h3>
            <form>
                <input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" ng-model="email"
                    placeholder="Email" /><br> <br> <input type="password"
                    class="resizedTextbox" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" /><br>
                <br> <input type="submit" class="resizedBtn" value="LogIn">
                <div id="signUpDiv">
                    Not a member yet? <a href="html/signUp.html">SignUp Now</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My signUp.html:

```
<html ng-app="Sample">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/custom.css" />
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="wrapper1" align="center">
        <div>
            <img id="logoDiv" src="../images/favicon.png">
        </div>
        <div id="loginDiv">
            <h3>Sign up</h3>
            <form>
                <input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email" /><br> <br>
                <input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" placeholder="Password" /><br><br> 
                 <input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" placeholder="Verify Password" /><br><br> 
               <a href="#/signUp"> <button class="resizedBtn" value="SIGN UP">SignUp
                </button></a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My script.js :

```
var app = angular.module('Sample', [ 'ngRoute' ]);
app.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/signUp', {
        // controller :'signUpController',
        templateUrl : '../signIn.html'
    })

} ]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect by routing in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529129/redirect-by-routing-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

Use this after your registration success.

```
 $location.path('/signinpath');
```

For this you need to inject   [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service

Comment: can u please edit the code over here as I'm a beginner to angularjs

Comment: I have tried using location.path,but I'm unable to load a page

Comment: For that I need your JavaScript code where you get success of registration.Please share that piece of code